# Remove Microsoft Edge from Windows Search Results

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, microsoft-edge

I have been trying to remove references to Edge from my start menu in Windows 10, since it can't be uninstalled, however I can't work out how to remove it from the search results in the 'Search Windows' box as well, is this possible?

If you want to know why the reason is you can't install addons to Edge so there's no way to get a leechblock equivalent. To solve this problem with IE I just removed all the shortcuts etc so it no longer comes up in search, but this is what I can't do for Edge at the moment.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear but does [How To Remove/Disable Web Search From Windows 10](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-disable-web-search-from-windows-10/) do what you want?

Comment: Only works doe W10 Pro or higher, as GPE is not included in lower versions.

Comment: No this wasn't really what I wanetd to do. You can also disable the bing search for each user in the search settings though, but useful to know it can be done in GP as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perfectly disable or delete Edge and Cortana and anything else if you wish.

How do i uninstall Microsoft Edge and Cortana

Go to C:\Windows\SystemApps

One of the folders in SystemApps refers to Edge and another refers to Cortana.

Read carefully the folder names and there will be no doubt.

Take ownership of the folders and grant yourselves full control

I will show you this for one folder

Elevated CMD prompt

> takeown /f C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Enter

> icacls C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe /grant administrators:f

Enter

Double-click the folder (open it) to see all the files

What we are looking for are Applications NOT Apllication Extensions

Inside the Edge folder you will find two applications that make Edge work.
MicrosoftEdge.exe and MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe

If you want to you have the full permission to delete these. But, JIC you want to use them afterwards . . .

Rename those files as .old (instead of the .exe) If you want to go back simply rename them back to .exe

Do the same procedure with the Cortana folder